# drive in the US while visiting

Tags: usa, driving-licenses

Can you drive in the US while you visit if you own a driver's license from your own country?if yes, for how long? I heard that you can for 6months.

Comment: The question as it stands now is too broad, you need to tell us which country do you intent to visit. Anyway in general you can drive using your license in a foreign country almost anywhere.

Comment: I guess it does not say much about the driver's license from asian countries to the americas or european countries. The answers were the other way around. We all know that US or European or Australian DLs have more bearing in the asian countries...

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is considered too broad is that US driving regulations depend on the state. Here is [an official US government website on driving as a visitor](http://www.usa.gov/Topics/Foreign-Visitors-Driving.shtml) giving you links to check up on the regulations for the states you will be visiting. Most states permit license holders from most countries to drive as a visitor for some amount of time, but you should check for your case.